# FLUTTER ANDROID ONLY: sent location data to REST API continuously even when my app is minimized/closed

Tags: android, flutter, rest, dart, http

I want to continuously send location data to REST API (PATCH METHODS) even when my app is minimized/closed. I put my function on InitState, but when I minimized the app.. the function is gone,

How can I avoid this so I can Patch my data continually?

Thanks!